# How to get the attributes of an invisible WebElement

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The webpage I'm testing has a collection of 35 checkboxes. 
The input tag is styled in such a way that it is positioned outside the visible part of the page (-9999px). When I want to click on it an ElementNotVisibleException appears. I can click on the label of the checkbox instead so this is not a problem but how to get the information if a checkbox is selected or not. The only way I can imagine is by analysing the page source. Is there another more convenient possibility to get this information?

Comment: If you have a specific issue, you should update the programming language used, the code you tried, the error you got and html snippet if needed. In this way you may receive more specific answers.

Comment: I'm using C# but I didn't mentioned it because in my opinion it is a general Selenium issue and not related tot the language I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you could try:

- you should already have a method like isChecked() to test this, find that method
- find the element and check his attribute for when is checked (example checked="checked")
- write another selector for that element and check that this selector exists(not visible), example with css:  input#elementID[checked=checked]  or by value, depending if is a checkbox or radio box

For invisible element you can get his attributes, you just are not able to interact with him and it will fail to check that is visible/displayed.

Use a method to find the element, this will return an object, and see what autocomplete offers, what methods you have available and you can use, you should have getAttribute, isChecked etc.

Comment: You were right, you can not interact with invisble elements like clicking on it but it's possible to get the attributes of it. With the .Selected method I managed to figure out if a Checkbox is selected or not.